# Is it possible to use Amazon Cloudfront sign URLs for attachments using Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, amazon-cloudfront

I am using Paperclip to store image attachments on Amazon S3 and deliver them through Cloudfront. I was looking around and was unable to find examples of it being used with signed URL's to protect the content. I was wondering if anyone here knows how to do this?

Thanks,

Leonard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit late, but never too late for people looking for an answer.

Upload your pictures to S3 as you will normally do, set `s3_permissions` to private so they have no public access through S3. Set `s3_host_alias` so paperclip uses that host, when asking for the attachment's URL and then just sign that URL.

You can use both signed URLs or signed cookies. For example, with the `cloudfront-signer` gem:

```
has_attached_file :photo,
                  s3_permissions: :private,
                  s3_host_alias: "dcx01yp1dg1u1.cloudfront.net"

# Now photo.url will point to dcx01yp1dg1u1.cloudfront.net instead of S3
Aws::CF::Signer.sign_url photo.url, expires: Time.now + 600
```

See https://github.com/leonelgalan/cloudfront-signer#usage for additional details. Disclaimer, I'm the current maintainer of this gem.

Comment: Thanks - but could you provide an example of using the gem with Paperclip? It's easy to be able to get a signed URL, but making it work nicely with Paperclip is the hard part. Thanks!

Comment: See updated answer, you upload normally to S3, and set `s3_host_alias` to retrieve images through CloudFront.